# awk: for-loop with break option

Tags: awk, for

I am trying to use `awk` to manipulate data.I have a data file with two columns and I would like to find the row that contains an specific value. But there is more than one row that contains this value and I only would like to find the first one. I tried it with a `for`-loop and `break` but it does not work the way I expected.

```
{for (i=0;$2==100.0;min=$1){
        i++
        max=min+500
        if(i==1){
            print i"\t"min"\t"max
            break
            }
        }
}
```

After this loop there is a little bit more code which utilizes `min` and `max`.

**Edit:** The data looks like this

```
59.45   96
59.50   96
59.60   97
59.75   98
59.90   98
59.95   98
60.00   99
60.05   99
60.20   99
60.25   100
60.40   100
60.45   100
60.50   101
60.55   101
60.60   101
60.65   101
60.70   102
60.90   102
60.95   103
61.00   103
61.05   103
61.15   103
61.20   104
61.35   104
61.40   104
61.45   105
61.50   105
61.60   105
61.65   106
61.70   100
61.85   100
```

I would like to find the first row that contains `100`in the second column and save the value from column one in a variable

Comment: What is the full command you had run?

Comment: Can you also provide some example dataset?

Comment: @Gnouc: I am just saving the code above in a file named test.awk and run it with `awk -f test.awk old.dat > new.dat`

Comment: @Froop: So I think it failed because you never enter for loop. The condition `$2==100.0` false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have a working solution

```
BEGIN {
    SearchMinFlag = 0;
    TempLimit = 195.0
    DeltaTime = 550
    TempMin = "LEER"
    FS = "\t"
}

# Stop MinSearch
NR > 2 && $1 > tstop {SearchMinFlag = 0}

# MinSearch
SearchMinFlag == 1 {
    ywert = $2;
    if (ywert < TempMin) {
        TempMin = ywert;
        TimeMin = $1
        }
}

# Start MinSearch
NR > 2 && $2 > TempLimit && SearchMinFlag == 0 && TempMin == "LEER" {
        SearchMinFlag = 1;
        tstart = $1
        tstop = tstart + DeltaTime
        ymerk = $2;
        TempMin = 10000
    }

# Result
END {
    print "t(T_min)", "T_min", "t_start", "t_stop\n"TimeMin, TempMin, tstart, tstop
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a for loop like that. Try something like:

```
awk '$2==100{print 1,$1,$1+500; exit}' OFS='\t' file
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an error message that `break is not allowed outside of a loop`.

Comment: @Froop Oww I meant `exit` of course. Changed it..